# Bounty expiring without result

Tags: discussion, bounty

I offered my first bounty worth 50 reputation.I have 2 hours to award the bounty including grace period, no previous experience with it. But there are no answers. It was earlier put on hold and it was lifted after what I consider sufficient explanation to elicit a response about morphing/isometry parameter.

Anyway on the topic of cylinder/tetrahedron isometry there appears no formulation is in existence at this point of time perhaps anywhere, even if I consider it a simple geometrical exercise.

A demo has worth of many equations in invoking a derivation.so I shall after sometime give a demo using a plastic sheet in a video. I procured material already. Is a short video permitted here?

Please advice what needs to be done at the time of bounty expiry if nowhere to go?

Answer (score 7):

In case there are no answers, there is nothing for you to do. The bounty will simply be gone (you will not get the points back).